# Merging the bands of a single image in GEE python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, multi-band, geemap, image-encoding

I currently have a single image with 3 bands with different turbidity data, all from the same region. The pixel values of the 3 bands do not overlap with each other. I would like to merge these 3 bands into one, while keeping the turbidity data intact.

Just as an example, I made 1 image, with multiple bands from a image collection:

```
Image1 = Collection1.toBands()
```

The image made from this collection looks something like this

```
Image1
band1: 0, 0, 0, 2
band2: 0, 0, 2, 0
band3: 2, 0, 0, 0
```

I would like to transform this into a single image with 1 band, for example:

```
Image2:
band1: 2, 0, 2, 2
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to create an image mosaic:

```
mosaic1 = Collection1.mosaic()
```

Tutorial on compositing and mosaicing: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_composite_mosaic